# Is there to shorten `def self.method_name` and `def method_name` into one method?

Tags: ruby

So say I have this class:

```
class This
  def a(that)
    puts that
  end

  def self.b(that)
    puts that
  end
end

This.b("Hello!") # => passes
This.a("Hello!") # => fails

the_class = This.new()
the_class.b("Hello!") # => fails
the_class.a("Hello!") # => passes
```

Is there a way to shorten both of those methods into one method that is able to be called on a uninitialized object, AND is able to be called on an already initialized one, or will I always have to write a method like that twice?

Comment: What do you mean by uninitialized object?

Comment: I mean that I haven't done `the_class = This.new()`. I don't know the proper term for that, sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract the functionality into a module and both `extend` and `include` it.

```
module A
  def a(that)
    puts that
  end
end

class This
  include A # defines instance methods
  extend A # defines class methods
end

This.a("foo") # => "foo"
This.new.a("foo") # => "foo"
```

Although I think it's more common to either `include` or `extend` and not both. The reason being that instance methods often depend on instance state, whereas class methods don't. If you have an instance `This.new` and want to call a class method, you can use `.class` i.e. `This.new.class.a`

Comment: The OP has effectively asked if a single method can have as its receiver either a class or an instance of a class. You haven't answered that. It seems to me that your main point is that one could simulate that by creating two methods with the same name, one a class method, the other an instance method. Using `include` and `extend` with a module is merely a convenient way of doing that.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

The following bit of code uses some metaprogramming tricks to auto copy over any class methods to instances of that class.

```
module AutoAddMethods

  def singleton_method_added(symbol)
    define_method(symbol, method(symbol).to_proc)
  end

end

class Foo
  extend AutoAddMethods
  @bar = 39

  def initialize
    @bar = 42
  end

  def test_one # Only added as an instance method.
    puts "One #{@bar.inspect}"
  end

  def self.test_two # Added as both an instance and class method.
    puts "Two #{@bar.inspect}"
  end

end

i = Foo.new
i.test_one
i.test_two

Foo.test_two
```

And here is my test run output:

```
One 42
Two 39
Two 39
```

The test_two method is callable from both the class and its instances. It runs as if in the class.

Comment: This is some handy code, I'll definitely using it in my some of my projects!